# Affine group, $[L : \mathbb{Q}] = n\varphi(n)$ or ${1\over2}n\varphi(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ be the Galois closure of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a})$, where $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, $a > 0$ and suppose $[K : \mathbb{Q}] = n$. How do I see that $[L: \mathbb{Q}] = n\varphi(n)$ or ${1\over2}n\varphi(n)$?

**Remarks.**

- Note that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) \cap K$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.
- Is there a way to use the affine group here?

Comment: Found [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/143739/galois-group-of-xn-2) this [reference](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102806302). It appears to go back to [this 1927 paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02409988).

Comment: A good find @Andreas. Thanks! Michael Zieve's argument using the norm shows that $K\cap \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is at most quadratic for any positive $a$. At least I think it does :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, indeed. The only part in the argument of the MO answer where $a=2$ is used is to have $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m] a):\Bbb Q]=m$, but in this case the equality holds as well, for if $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m] a):\Bbb Q]<m$, this would imply $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n] a):\Bbb Q]<n$.